# Why two Kafka brockers for one queue table in clickhouse Kafka engine do not work simultaneously?

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

I have quite simple setup for inserting data from Kafka to Clickhouse table. My data stream is as follows:

```
create table vflow.queue_ng
(
    message String
)
    engine = Kafka SETTINGS
        kafka_broker_list = '100.127.201.11:9092,100.127.203.13:9092',
        kafka_topic_list = 'netflow',
        kafka_group_name = 'catflow_ng',
        kafka_format = 'JSONAsString';
```

But this table gets data stream **only from one broker**! The first or the second one, but not from both ones simultaneously.

With each broker (if it is used as the only one) it works fine.

I tried to use queue table with one brocker as follows:

```
create table vflow.queue_ng
(
    message String
)
    engine = Kafka SETTINGS
        kafka_broker_list = '100.127.203.13:9092',
        kafka_topic_list = 'netflow',
        kafka_group_name = 'catflow_ng',
        kafka_format = 'JSONAsString';
```

with absolutely no problem, but if I add the second brocker and recreate table with kafka_broker_list = '100.127.201.11:9092,100.127.203.13:9092' it gets data only from one source.

Comment: Are you saying it simply doesn't work with more than one? Otherwise, how do you know the data only comes from one? Are both addresses even part of the same Kafka cluster?

Comment: I have 2 Kafka instances and 2 instances of vflow traffic collector. Each vflow feeds its own kafka instance with the same topic. Then clickhouse collects data from both. (But in fact only from one, and this is the problem).

Comment: I dont know what Vflow is. "2 Kafka instances" doesn't matter as long as it is **one cluster**. You cannot put cross-cluster addresses that denote separate Kafka clusters in the broker_list

Comment: These 2 instanses of Kafka are the separate and independent ones, no cluster.

Comment: Then, like I said, it won't work

Comment: This fact is not described in clickhouse documentation. Thanx.

Comment: It shouldn't have to be, IMO. That's how any Kafka client works

Answer (score 2):

How many partitions are for that topic?
Partitions are distributed between brokers. If you have one partition it will be read, only from one broker.
If you have more than one partition then the issue can be all messages are written to one partition if the message key is not optimal.
The third thing is the replication factor for the topic.

Comment: Topic: netflow  TopicId: vBgb04tyQaiRvUivFGzudQ PartitionCount: 8       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: flush.ms=1000

Comment: How are you writing data to your topic?  You might have 8 partitions but if you are only writing to one it will only be on one broker.

Comment: Replication factor doesn't matter for distributed consumption

Answer (score 0):

> These 2 instanses of Kafka are the separate and independent ones, no cluster.

Then Clickhouse will bootstrap to the first available "cluster" from that list of broker addresses.

Similarly, your producer processes are only sending data to those servers, individually.

If you want to join data from distinct Kafka clusters (even clusters of one instance), you need two different table definitions, then join/union the data in a query